# C# UWP setting MP3 thumbnail image

Tags: c#, uwp

Is there some possibility in C# UWP to set the COVER image of a MP3 file (that is a type of StorageFile)?

I have currently a refernce to the file (StorageFile), can read properties of the file (file.Properties.GetMusicPropertiesAsync()) and I would like to set the image of this "Media File" with the BitmapImage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use taglib to access the tag properties of a file. Check here https://www.nuget.org/packages/taglib/

here are some examples on using the library https://csharp.hotexamples.com/examples/-/TagLib.File/-/php-taglib.file-class-examples.html

Comment: I am sorry meant with Thumbnail the Cover of the MP3 when you play the song.

Comment: I updated my answer based on your needs. You can use taglib to achieve your goal. See above :)